# how to use ip address in xsl

Tags: jquery, xslt

I'm using xsl to generate html from xsl. I have to use ip address in name of the class in css like this:

```
<td><div title="delete" >
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
         delete_link_<xsl:value-of select="destinationIp"/>
    </xsl:attribute>    
    <img class="row-remover" src="/media/img/remove.png"/>
</div></td>
```

and i have this jquery function:

```
 $('.delete_link_<xsl:value-of select="destinationIp"/>').click( function() {
      // do some thing here
 });
```

but because there are 'dots' in ip address, the above code doesn't work. when i remove dots of destinationIp tag in xml file, it works. so i think it has problem with 'dot'. any idea to make it work? really thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just deleting the dots can have *bad* consequences**.

Consider these two IP addresses:

```
13.8.123.4
```

and

```
138.12.3.4
```

When dots are deleted, we get exactly the same result in each of the two cases:

```
1381234
```

**I believe that you want to have a different class for each IP address. If so, don't delete the dots, but replace them with a legal character**:

```
<td><div title="delete" class="delete_link{translate(destinationIp,'.','_')}">
    <img class="row-remover" src="/media/img/remove.png"/>
</div></td>
```

**Using this code produces two different classes for the two IP addresses above**:

```
delete_link13_8_123_4
```

and

```
delete_link138_12_3_4
```

**Do note also, how your original code was shrunk twice** (from 6 to 3 lines) by using AVT (**[Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)**).

Comment: yeah, your right, really thanks for your useful and kind help :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey man you will escape the ip address like this: use `\\` before each special characters, that will do the trick.

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gubfj/

**sample**

`127\\.0\\.0\\.1`

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jquery-en/ugchaJObJFo

> Use two backslashes before each special character.
>
> A backslash in a jQuery selector escapes the next character. But you
>   need two of them because backslash is also the escape character for
>   JavaScript strings. The first backslash escapes the second one, giving
>   you one actual backslash in your string - which then escapes the next
>   character for jQuery.

Hope this fit the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$('.delete127\\.0\\.0\\.1').click( function() {
     alert("you click ==> " + $(this).html());
      // do some thing here
 });​
```

Comment: really thanks, but my problem is destinationIp is in xml file, and i know i can access it by '<xsl:value-of select="destinationIp"/>' , but how can i use backslash in it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but because i'm writing in xsl file, when i write "\\<xsl\\", it shows me error because of not closing tag :(

Comment: @user1597122 can you try to use my demo and crete your issue `:)` please, I might be off to bed soon, but I will take a look. `:))`

Comment: hmmm... really sorry, i need to write xsl, but i can't find a place in your demo to write it. but when i tried in my own code(in my xsl file), the error says that xsl tag is not closed.
have a nice dream :)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove dot characters from a string using the translate() function.

For example...

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate( destinationIp, '.', '')"/>
```

Refer:

1. http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_translate.html
2. (XSLT 1.0) http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate  OR
3. (XSLT 2.0) http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-translate